# logrotate daily and size?

Tags: logrotate

If a logrotate config is specified with "size" and "daily" parameters, which one takes precedence? Where is this documented? I would like these rotations to occur as a boolean OR operation, ie, if the logs are a day old they get rotated, OR if they are larger than a certain size they will also get rotated. However, logrotate is currently only using the "size" directive, and appears to be ignoring the "daily" directive. Logrotate is set up to run every hour. OS is linux, Red Hat and Debian derivatives.

Also, I am specifying "daily" first, then "size" from the start of the file. Not sure if the order matters, but in any case, one has to come first in the config file...

Thanks!

Comment: Also see http://serverfault.com/questions/474941/how-to-rotate-log-based-on-an-interval-unless-log-exceeds-a-certain-size?rq=1

Comment: > local definitions override global ones, and **later definitions
> override earlier ones** from the manpage of logrotate 3.8.7

Answer (score 80):

If the **size** directive is used, logrotate will ignore the **daily**, **weekly**, **monthly**, and **yearly** directives. This is not clear in the documentation when you execute the `man logrotate` command. However it can be confirmed in practice, and is mentioned in some arbitrary blog posts [such as this one](http://linuxnextgen.blogspot.com/2011/04/logrotate-in-linux.html).

There is a directive called **minsize** which according to the logrotate man page is the only size directive that can be used in conjunction with the time ones. However, its still not what you want. Using **minsize** with **daily** essentially says: *rotate the logs daily, but only when they are at least #MB in size*.

To date I have found no way with logrotate to do the condition you require: *rotate every day, unless the size exceeds #MB, in which case rotate immediately*. I do not think this is supported using only logrotate directives. It might be possible to do with some clever scripting via the script hook directives like **prerotate**, **postrotate**, **firstaction**, and **lastaction**.

**Update**:

As of logrotate 3.8.1, `maxsize` and `timeperiod` are supported together, which would be the ideal solution. See the answer to this post: [How to rotate log based on an interval unless log exceeds a certain size?](https://serverfault.com/questions/474941/how-to-rotate-log-based-on-an-interval-unless-log-exceeds-a-certain-size)

Comment: Best option would probably be to use two separate cron commands, run to run it daily with the default conf, and one every x minutes that takes a config with just the files that you worry about overflow using the size directive and not the daily.

Comment: As of logrotate 3.8.1, `maxsize` and `timeperiod` are supported. Per http://serverfault.com/questions/474941/how-to-rotate-log-based-on-an-interval-unless-log-exceeds-a-certain-size

Comment: @belacqua I am using 3.8.7 and timeperiod is not in the man.

Comment: The correct version is actually 3.8.1, not 3.81.

Answer (score 5):

The first answer by @egg is, according to my experiences with logrotate, not true!

If **daily, monthly, ...** come **first** and after that **size** directive, **daily, monthly, ...** will be ignored and **size** directive will apply to the log file.

Similarly when I first use the **size** directive then **daily, weekly, monthly, and yearly** directives, the **size** directive will be ignored.

Comment: And the **daily**, **monthly**, **...** and **size** must come before directive **include /path/of/logrotate.d/** to take effect for each specific log file configured in **/path/of/logrotate.d/**.

Answer (score 1):

If you add Daily it is going to rotate each day even if the Size condition is met. If you add the size condition as well you may get two rotations in one day depending on how verbose the logging is.

If Daily goes first in the script then Size may not fire off.

Comment: use the verbose option to see which rules are used.  From my tests I believe only the last rule is used because more specific rules can override more general rules.

Comment: More rotations are OK, as that would be the expected behavior. (boolean OR) However, my issue is that these rotations are not occurring. It appears to be a bug (possibly a feature) of log rotate, as I can not see the order of directives being important or documented anywhere.

Comment: can you give an example of your logrotate.conf and the files you are trying to target? Daily does not have a condition other then time progression. Size is conditional.

Comment: /tmp/output.log {
        daily
        size 1k
        rotate 5
}

Comment: This file gets rotated when the size is greater than 1k, but it is *not* rotated daily as expected and desired.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, my man page on Red Hat appears to be pretty clear on the differences between size and minsize:

> minsize size
>
> ```
>           Log  files  are rotated when they grow bigger then size bytes,
>           but  not  before  the  additionally  specified  time  interval
>           (daily,  weekly, monthly, or yearly).  The related size option
>           is similar except that it is mutually exclusive with the  time
>           interval  options, and it causes log files to be rotated with-
>           out regard for the last rotation time.  When minsize is  used,
>           both the size and timestamp of a log file are considered.
> ```