# Issue with logrotate log based on an interval unless log exceeds a certain size?

Tags: logrotate

I went though few resources in this forum like:
[How to rotate log based on an interval unless log exceeds a certain size?](https://serverfault.com/questions/474941/how-to-rotate-log-based-on-an-interval-unless-log-exceeds-a-certain-size?newreg=663636df9b864ebcb7b8c8e11beb58b1)
but, I don't see my log files being rotated daily.
their max size for past couple of weeks are less than 10MB, but the Maxsize 10MB + daily should compress the file daily right?

> ```
> /apps/alfresco-4.2.4/tomcat/logs/catalina.out {
>     missingok
>     maxsize 10MB + daily
>     create 0755 mwtcs mwtcs
>     rotate 1
>   notifempty
>   dateext
>   compress
> }
> ```

What is wrong with my code? What am I missing here?
I'm new to this task.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't have enough credits/reputation to add tags like maxsize, daily rotate etc :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `rotate 1` to how many times you want to rotate your log file before it will be deleted. Right now it will rotate only once. Only one file is hold.

> their max size for past couple of weeks are less than 10MB, but the
>   Maxsize 10MB + daily should compress the file daily right?

When the max size is reached (10M) file is truncated and - in your case - file will be always lower than 10M.

Check this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UoHmj3ef3Is  if you want to learn logrotate.

Small Update:
So, using `rotate 10` and `maxsize 10M` is good if you have static amount of space for logs. Lets say 1GB of space = `rotate 100` and `maxsize 10M`.

**maxsize size**

> Log files are rotated when they grow bigger than size
>   bytes even before the additionally specified time interval (daily,
>   weekly, monthly, or yearly) ...

Your another question asked in comments should be asked in another topic, but here it goes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27566659/4948699

**maxage count**

> Remove rotated logs older than  days. The age is only checked if the logfile is to be rotated.

Comment: After watching the video, which has rotate 99, means, 99 copies. Since, mine is rotate 1, I'm keeping only one copy. My requirements are to save records of past six months.
So, my code change should be "rotate 180". correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: No, you should use `maxage count` check man page. Right now, you would store 10M (or more M) files 180 times. Who knows if 10M is enought for one day log? ... I'll update answer in about ~40min, right now afk.

Comment: I gave you already explanation: read Jan Vlcinsky post from stackoverflow link.